# how can i align bootstrap 4 dropdown menu to left and expand to full length

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In the above code am trying to align the dropdown to left and with full width as i have tried different measures for solving it by adding dropdown-menu-left or pull-left by seems like it's not working for me, i want it to work the following dropdown as we can see in poorishaadi.com but am unable to fix it, it will be great if anyone can help am using simple bootstrap to work this code.

```css
.navbar-nav>li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dropdown>.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 570px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.multi-column-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  white-space: normal;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f80606;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    min-width: 240px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white 
    sticky-top ">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand "><img src="images/Logo.png" width="200" height="60"></a><button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsenavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="collapsenavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu multi-column" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li><a href="caterers.php">Caterers</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="decorer.php">Decorator</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="dholwale.php">Dhol Wale</a></li>
                  <hr />
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li><a href="flowrdecor.php">Flower Decorator</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="makeupart.php">Makeup Artist</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="mehandi.php">Mehandi Artist</a></li>
                  <hr />
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li><a href="photo.php">Photography</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="sound.php">Sound & DJ</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="Venue_1.php">Venue</a></li>
                  <hr />
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li><a href="cards.php">Wedding Cards</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="Wedplan.php">Wedding Planner</a></li>
                  <hr />
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `position-static` class to your `<li>` items and then add the class `w-100` to your dropdown menu to make it full width.

See your modified code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white sticky-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand "><img src="images/Logo.png" width="200" height="60"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsenavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="collapsenavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active position-static">
            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="index.php">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services</a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu multi-column w-100" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                   <li><a href="caterers.php">Caterers</a></li>
                   <hr />
                   <li><a href="decorer.php">Decorator</a></li>
                   <hr />
                   <li><a href="dholwale.php">Dhol Wale</a></li>
                   <hr />
                </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                   <li><a href="flowrdecor.php">Flower Decorator</a></li>
                   <hr />
                   <li><a href="makeupart.php">Makeup Artist</a></li>
                   <hr />
                   <li><a href="mehandi.php">Mehandi Artist</a></li>
                   <hr />
                </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                   <li><a href="photo.php">Photography</a></li>
                   <hr />
                   <li><a href="sound.php">Sound & DJ</a></li>
                   <hr />
                   <li><a href="Venue_1.php">Venue</a></li>
                   <hr />
                </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                   <li><a href="cards.php">Wedding Cards</a></li>
                   <hr />
                   <li><a href="Wedplan.php">Wedding Planner</a></li>
                   <hr />
                </ul>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </li>

 </ul>
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nxvc0yL/) too (to see it in action).

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on this solution.

Currently your `dropdown-menu` is relative to the `nav-item`. 
It should be relative to the outer full width `container`...

```css
.navbar-nav>li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dropdown>.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 570px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.multi-column-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  white-space: normal;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f80606;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    min-width: 240px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}


/* Extra added */

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-item {
  position: static !important;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white 
sticky-top ">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand "><img src="images/Logo.png" width="200" height="60"></a><button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsenavbar">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="collapsenavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu multi-column" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li><a href="caterers.php">Caterers</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="decorer.php">Decorator</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="dholwale.php">Dhol Wale</a></li>
                  <hr />
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li><a href="flowrdecor.php">Flower Decorator</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="makeupart.php">Makeup Artist</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="mehandi.php">Mehandi Artist</a></li>
                  <hr />
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li><a href="photo.php">Photography</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="sound.php">Sound & DJ</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="Venue_1.php">Venue</a></li>
                  <hr />
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                  <li><a href="cards.php">Wedding Cards</a></li>
                  <hr />
                  <li><a href="Wedplan.php">Wedding Planner</a></li>
                  <hr />
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `text-center` class from the `<div id="collapsenavbar">`. Below are the updated code:

```css
.navbar-nav > li{
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 570px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
.multi-column-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  white-space: normal;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f80606;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    min-width: 240px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white 
sticky-top ">
<div class="container">
  <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand "><img src="images/Logo.png" width="200" height="60"></a><button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsenavbar">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsenavbar">
     <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
           <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services</a>
           <div class="dropdown-menu multi-column" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                       <li><a href="caterers.php">Caterers</a></li>
                       <hr />
                       <li><a href="decorer.php">Decorator</a></li>
                       <hr />
                       <li><a href="dholwale.php">Dhol Wale</a></li>
                       <hr />
                    </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                       <li><a href="flowrdecor.php">Flower Decorator</a></li>
                       <hr />
                       <li><a href="makeupart.php">Makeup Artist</a></li>
                       <hr />
                       <li><a href="mehandi.php">Mehandi Artist</a></li>
                       <hr />
                    </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                       <li><a href="photo.php">Photography</a></li>
                       <hr />
                       <li><a href="sound.php">Sound & DJ</a></li>
                       <hr />
                       <li><a href="Venue_1.php">Venue</a></li>
                       <hr />
                    </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                       <li><a href="cards.php">Wedding Cards</a></li>
                       <hr />
                       <li><a href="Wedplan.php">Wedding Planner</a></li>
                       <hr />
                    </ul>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **position-relative** class to your main **container** and then **remove position-relative** from **.navbar-nav > li.nav-item.dropdown** and add **width:100%** to **.dropdown > .dropdown-menu** to make it full width.

```css
.navbar-nav > li{
        padding-left:10px;
        padding-right:10px;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li.nav-item.dropdown {
        position: inherit;
    }
    .dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
        min-width: 570px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .multi-column-dropdown {
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 20px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .multi-column-dropdown li a {
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        line-height: 1.428571429;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        white-space: normal;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #f80606;
    }
    .nav-wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
        min-width: 240px !important;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white sticky-top ">
    <div class="container nav-wrapper">
      <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand "><img src="images/Logo.png" width="200" height="60"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsenavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="collapsenavbar">
         <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
               <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
               <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services</a>
               <div class="dropdown-menu multi-column" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                           <li><a href="caterers.php">Caterers</a></li>
                           <hr />
                           <li><a href="decorer.php">Decorator</a></li>
                           <hr />
                           <li><a href="dholwale.php">Dhol Wale</a></li>
                           <hr />
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                           <li><a href="flowrdecor.php">Flower Decorator</a></li>
                           <hr />
                           <li><a href="makeupart.php">Makeup Artist</a></li>
                           <hr />
                           <li><a href="mehandi.php">Mehandi Artist</a></li>
                           <hr />
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                           <li><a href="photo.php">Photography</a></li>
                           <hr />
                           <li><a href="sound.php">Sound & DJ</a></li>
                           <hr />
                           <li><a href="Venue_1.php">Venue</a></li>
                           <hr />
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                           <li><a href="cards.php">Wedding Cards</a></li>
                           <hr />
                           <li><a href="Wedplan.php">Wedding Planner</a></li>
                           <hr />
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </li>

         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```